# Prove/disprove: $f(x,y)=\{\{x\},\{y,\emptyset\}\}$ is an ordered pair map. (ZFC)

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-verification

> Prove/disprove: $f(x,y)=\{\{x\},\{y,\emptyset\}\}$ is an ordered pair map. (ZFC)

*Progress*:
We need to prove $f(x,y)=f(u,v)\iff x=u\quad \operatorname{and}\quad y=v$

*proof.*
$\impliedby$ is done by plugging.
$\implies$ we assume $f(x,y)=f(u,v)\iff \{\{x\},\{y,\emptyset\}\}=\{\{u\},\{v,\emptyset\}\}$

Case I: $(x=y)$
We have $\{\{x\},\{x,\emptyset\}\}=\{\{u\},\{v,\emptyset\}\}$.$\quad$

If $\{x\}=\{u\}$  $$x=u\implies\{\{x\},\{x,\emptyset\}\}=\{\{x\},\{v,\emptyset\}\}\implies x=y=u=v$$If $\{x\}=\{v,\emptyset\}$ $$x=v=\emptyset\implies\{\{x\}\}=\{\{u\},\{x\}\}\implies x=y=u=v$$Case II: $(x\neq y)$
If $\{x\}=\{v,\emptyset\}$  $$x=v=\emptyset\implies\{\{x\},\{y,x\}\}=\{\{u\},\{x\}\}\implies\{u\}=\{y,x\}\implies u=x=y \Rightarrow\!\Leftarrow$$Otherwise, $\{x\}=\{u\}$ $$x=u\implies \{\{x\},\{y,\emptyset\}\}=\{\{x\},\{v,\emptyset\}\}\implies y=v$$   *comment*:
I'm not sure about this proof. Furthermore, am I *over-checking* something in Case I? (and do I even need Case I?)

Comment: Comment: you don’t suppose that $f(x,y)=f(u,v)\iff \{\;\{x\},\{y,\varnothing\}\} = \{\;\{u\},\{v,\varnothing\}\}$. You are asserting that your assumption si that the equivalence holds. The only thing you are assuming is that $f(x,y)=f(u,v)$.

Comment: I don’t see why you need to consider the cases of $x=y$ and $x\neq y$ separately. Assume that $f(x,y)=f(u,v)$. If $\{x\}=\{v,\varnothing\}$, then $x=v=\varnothing$, in particular, $f(u,v)$ consists of singletons, so $\{y,\varnothing\}$ is a singleton, hence $y=\varnothing=v=x$; then $f(x,y)$ is a singleton, so $\{u\}=\{v,\varnothing\}=\{\varnothing\}$, so $u=v=x=y=\varnothing$. If $\{x\}\neq \{v,\varnothing\}$, then $\{x\}=\{u\}$, and in particular $\{y,\varnothing\}\neq\{x\}$; thus $\{\{y,\varnothing\}\} = f(x,y)-\{x\} = f(u,v)-\{x\}=f(u,v)-\{u\} = \{\{v,\varnothing\}\}$, and conclude $y=v$.

Comment: (third line) why does $\{y,\emptyset\}$ being a singleton not imply $y=u=\emptyset$?

Comment: Who said it didn’t? It implies lots of things; I can’t put all of them as first consequence.